500 Error: Hostname/IP Does Not Match Certificate's Altnames When Using Nodemailer to Send Email to GMAIL
The contact form works seamlessly locally but encounters a 500 internal server error when deployed on the A2Hosting server.
Live Website
Form functionality
The form allows users to submit their name, email, and message. Upon submission, the message is sent via SMTP to a Gmail email address using nodemailer.
All required env variables are added to the node app using cpanel.
app.js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Serve static files
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "assets")));
app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "css")));
app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "js")));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "images")));
app.use("/fonts", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "fonts")));

// Rate limiting middleware
const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
    max: 5, // limit each IP to 5 requests per windowMs
    message: "Too many requests from this IP, please try again later",
});

app.use("/send-email", limiter);

// Route to handle form submission
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, message } = req.body;

    console.log("Form data received:", { name, email, message });

    // Create a Nodemailer transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS,
        },
    });

    // Email message options
    const mailOptions = {
        from: email,
        to: process.env.RECIPIENT_EMAIL,
        subject: "New contact form submission",
        text: `Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\nMessage: ${message}`,
    };

    console.log("Attempting to send email with options:", mailOptions);

    // Send email
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error("Error sending email:", error);
            return res.status(500).send("Failed to send email");
        }

        console.log("Email sent successfully:", info.response);

        // Send mail-success.html with success.js
        res.sendFile(
            path.join(__dirname, "public", "html", "mail-success.html"),
            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Error sending mail-success.html:", err);
                    return res.status(500).send("Failed to send success page");
                }
            }
        );
    });
});

// Serve index.html for root path
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "html", "index.html"));
});

// Serve success.js for success page
app.get("/success.js", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "js", "success.js"));
});

// Error-handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send("Something broke!");
});

// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

HTML and CSS for form:
https://codepen.io/mepsrajput/pen/ExzKyrX
HTML, CSS and JS for success page:
https://codepen.io/mepsrajput/pen/RwmaVYp
Error Log:
:"030A5E928AF20E66893536BF8A8F7356A0F1","subject":{"CN":"*.a2hosting.com"},"subjectaltname":"DNS:*.a2hosting.com","valid_from":"Apr 15 01:23:41 2024 GMT","valid_to":"Jul 14 01:23:40 2024 GMT"},"code":"ESOCKET","command":"CONN","host":"smtp.gmail.com","level":"error","message":"Error sending email: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: smtp.gmail.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.a2hosting.com","reason":"Host: smtp.gmail.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.a2hosting.com","stack":"Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: smtp.gmail.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.a2hosting.com\n    at Object.checkServerIdentity (node:tls:337:12)\n    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1684:27)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)\n    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)\n    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12)","timestamp":"2024-05-21T16:43:23.779Z"}
{"from":"!aak@a.a","level":"error","message":"Failed email options:","subject":"New contact form submission","text":"Name: aaa\nEmail: !aak@a.a\nMessage: aaa ajfl ajfal; f","timestamp":"2024-05-21T16:43:23.785Z","to":"viveksingh12126@gmail.com"}

